# How to read nested Azure Rest API JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, azure

I am trying to parse nested JSON data in PHP.

I have wriiten the following code.

```
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token; 

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxx-1faf-4756-a709-1af49be58e56/resourcegroups?api-version=2020-06-01',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization)
  ),
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
//echo $response;
$datarg=json_decode($response,true);


print_r($datarg);
```

The output which I am getting is like below.

```
Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => /subscriptions/xxxxx-1faf-4756-a709-1af49be58e56/resourceGroups/cloud-shell-storage-centralindia [name] => cloud-shell-storage-centralindia [type] => Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups [location] => centralindia [properties] => Array ( [provisioningState] => Succeeded ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => /subscriptions/xxxxx-1faf-4756-a709-1af49be58e56/resourceGroups/NetworkWatcherRG [name] => NetworkWatcherRG [type] => Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups [location] => eastus [properties] => Array ( [provisioningState] => Succeeded ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => /subscriptions/xxxxx-1faf-4756-a709-1af49be58e56/resourceGroups/AZREUSADRG [name] => AZREUSADRG [type] => Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups [location] => eastus [properties] => Array ( [provisioningState] => Succeeded ))))
```

But I only want the values of [Name] field to be stored in a variable or array so that I can use it later in drop down list. How can I do that? Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with a recursive function

```
// Recursive function to search by key
function search_recursive_by_key($arr, $searchkey){

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
       if (is_array($val)) {
          search_recursive_by_key($val, $searchkey);
 
       } else {
          if ($searchkey == $key) {
            
               
             echo("$val <br/>");
            }
       }
    }
 return;
 }

// Call function with Key as second argument
search_recursive_by_key($json, 'name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read name like below:

```
echo $datarg->value[0]->name;
```

Check out this great article on JSON parsing in PHP: [JSON Tutorial: Request API Data with JavaScript or PHP](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-json-data-with-php-or-javascript/).